# jQuery Finding Script Tags in AJAX Response String

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pulling an AJAX response HTML string with jQuery. I have some colliding scripts when I append this response to the document, so I wanted to remove it, and place it only after the offending original scripts are removed.

Here is my code (located in the success function of the ajax):

```
var content = $(response).find('.content').html();
var scripts = $(content).find('script');
console.log(scripts);
```

This code returns 0 scripts. However, when I do:

```
var content = $(response).find('.content').html();
var scripts = $(content).find('h3'); //PULLING H3s INSTEAD OF SCRIPT TAGS
console.log(scripts);
```

It returns all of the h3's in that string. What's going on here?

I can confirm that the script IS in the response string.

**Thanks all for the help. I ended up using hidden inputs in the documents, then using $.getScript() on the values of those. Everything is working, now.**

Comment: the script tags are stripped and executed when you do `$(response)`. Instead, you should use a regexp to replace script tags with divs, then after you turn it into DOM Nodes, select said divs, iterate over them, and process them. Or, don't include script tags in html that you're requesting with javascript. That's what i would do, it's far less error prone.

Comment: I don't want to include the script in the HTML, but it's for a client who wants a slideshow style site, where the pages are loaded with AJAX. A lot of these pages have scripts in them. I'm not really sure the correct way to do that.

Answer (score 2):

the script tags are stripped and executed when you do $(response). Instead, you should use a regexp to replace script tags with divs, then after you turn it into DOM Nodes, select said divs, iterate over them, and process them.

One way of doing that is:

```
function cleanInsert(html, target, htmlSelector, filter) {
    var outHTML = html, $content = $(target);
    outHTML = outHTML.replace(/<script/ig, "<div class='iscript'").replace(/<\/script/ig, '</script');
    outHTML = $("<div>").html(outHTML);
    outHTML = htmlSelector ? outHTML.find(htmlSelector) : outHTML.children();
    if (filter) {
        outHTML = filter.call(outHTML);
    }
    var scripts = outHTML.filter('div.iscript').detach();
    scripts.add(outHTML.find('div.iscript').detatch());
    $content.html(outHTML);
    scripts.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            s = document.createElement("script");
        if ($this.attr('src') != "") {
            s.src = $this.attr('src');
        } else {
            s.nodeValue = $this.text();
        }
        $content[0].appendChild(s);
    });
}​
//                   insert target response filter
cleanInsert(response, "#targetel", ".content");
```

not heavily tested.